# incrontab -e 'editor finished with error: No such file or directory'

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, incron, incrond

When I tried to add an incron entry I got this error.

```
incrontab -e
editor finished with error: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to the editor it is trying to run.

```
tail  /etc/incron.conf

# Parameter:   editor
# Meaning:     editor executable
# Description: This name or path is used to run as an editor for editing
#              user tables.
# Default:     vim
#
# Example:
# editor = nano
```

So if you try and run vim the default editor.

```
vim
-bash: vim: command not found
```

Fix this by installing vim or setting a different editor in the config file.

```
yum install vim
```

or

```
echo "editor = /usr/bin/vi" >> /etc/incron.conf
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I was trying to use it as user. Adding `root` to `/etc/incron.allow` and running `sudo incrontab -e` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @VictorLamoine You can also add your user to `/etc/incron.allow` and run `incrontab -e` as that user.